# Wake up my PC from suspend using a USB device (e.g. mouse)

Tags: 12.04, usb, mouse, suspend

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and I can't wake up my desktop PC from suspend with a USB device (e.g USB mouse). The entire process of suspending/resume works perfectly but the only way to resume it's by pressing the PWR Button. Here are some logs that I hope could help someone troubleshooting my issue: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6468990/.
I tried to follow this guide to enable wake up from USB devices but with no luck: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/220-ubuntu-resume-usb-hid. Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: External USB devices are powered off to save power - which coincidentally means that they will not work... With a USB mouse, is the light still on during suspend?

Comment: Nope, the light on the mouse during suspend is off. But the thing is, with the same setup that i have, wake up with mouse is correctly working on Windows 7 x64 (with also the mouse lights off during suspend). So at least i can say it's not a BIOS setting issue...

Comment: Try getting power supplied to it while the computer is suspended first, and then see if it works. Suspend is supposed to be power-saving, so it will probably be buried deep within the code that runs it.... or even the drivers...

Comment: Oh, and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=95659), demonstrates the inverse,I don't know whether you could lock the `/sys/bus/usb/devices/$port/power/level...` files to stop it turning it off when it suspends. Found [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5387/how-to-avoid-powering-down-certain-usb-devices-when-a-machine-is-suspended) as well, which is means that the power could still be supplied during suspend *(And I could run systems more efficiently off external hard disk :-) . )*

Comment: I tried the solution posted [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12348) as you suggested but still no luck, I think that power management on USB devices (and suspend too) has changed a lot, especially in recent kernels (i'm on 3.5.0-18-generic) and those posts are referring to previous versions. Also, as you can see from my logs in the op, i don't have any USBx entries in /proc/acpi/wakeup and i can't manually add them. I'm about to give up on this issue cause it's a jungle literally...

Comment: point I can see in this post is USB external drives, as those are an utter pain if the computer suspends. `acpi` I think needs to be installed anyway, but if it is possible to turn device off, it should be possible to stop them being turned off during suspend *(atleast I think so...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this issue by upgrading to the kernel v3.12.0. Now the whole process of suspend/resume, including wake up with my USB mouse works!

Comment: :-) *Stupid 15 characters*